# Debian Bullseye: Bluetooth of Dell Vostro 3500 missing

Tags: bluetooth, debian

In a fresh installation of Debian Bullseye 11.2 with Gnome including non-free packages i experience a missing Bluetooth support in my Dell Vostro 3500 - whereas Wifi works fine.

The symptoms are showing in the Gnome > Bluetooth dialog with "No Bluetooth found - Connect an adapter to be able to use Bluetooth." and in the terminal with

```sh
$ sudo systemctl status bluetooth
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Jan 04 10:42:42 debian systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

```sh
$ sudo systemctl cat bluetooth
# /lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service
[Unit]
..
ConditionPathIsDirectory=/sys/class/bluetooth
..
```

```sh
$ sudo ls -la /sys/class/bluetooth
ls: cannot access '/sys/class/bluetooth': No such file or directory
```

I checked the BIOS setup which confirms that Bluetooth is activated.
I checked and confirmed that the usual packages *firmware-misc-nonfree* and *firmware-iwlwifi* are installed.

Now i wonder in general what is missing to make Bluetooth work and in specific what it means that the folder /sys/classes/bluetooth is missing?

Data

- Computer: Dell Vostro 3500 (A12, F1SC9N1, bought in 2011)
- OS: Debian Bullseye 11.2
- ISO image: debian-live-11.2.0-amd64-gnome+nonfree.iso
- ISO image url: https://cdimage.debian.org/images/unofficial/non-free/images-including-firmware/11.2.0-live+nonfree/amd64/iso-hybrid/debian-live-11.2.0-amd64-gnome+nonfree.iso

Comment: First you should check whether the Linux kernel is able to load the correct kernel module. What does `dmesg` say? Moreover, this problem is 'off topic' on Stackoverflow and it would fit much better on one of the other sites, for example  https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 73359." - do you prefer a specific part of the dmesg output?